# EmberJS Routers and Nested Views

Tags: ember.js

I'm building an application that will have a few layers of subviews and I'm confused about how to build my router.  I'm fine with flat views all being substituted automatically into the uppermost {{outlet}}, but now my subviews will have subviews of their own.

Are there any examples of the new (pre4) EmberJS routers handling a tree of subviews?  The [Router Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) introduces the idea of a "resource", but I have no idea what that is, and I can't tell if it will help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example on how to use the resource method with Ember. The idea is to group routes that logically fit together. If you want to describe an interaction, say with products, you want to list, create, edit and delete products. Then your routes should be defined as

```
APP.Router.map(function(match) {
  this.resource("products", function(){
    this.route('new');
    this.route('edit',{path:'/edit/:id'});
    this.route('delete',{path:'/delete/:id'});
  });  
});
```

And then you can interact with the related views through the following urls

```
/#/products
/#/products/new
/#/products/edit/1
/#/products/delete/1
```

This, in a way, will help you describe your application in terms of states and sub-states.

Comment: This is definitely helping.  Thank you.

Comment: So to follow up on routers.  What if my app had a traditional tab view "A", "B", and "C".  And under "A" I had tabs "X", "Y", and "Z".  How would the route look?  Would I have a "{{outlet}}" inside of "A"?

Comment: you can use different outlets with different names i.e named outlets, when you render your template you get to decide which outlet you want to populate. See for more details http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: Oh perfect, I can specify a named outlet in the route.  I missed that.  It's all starting to make sense.  Thanks!